# Postman API's URL's with parameters is empty on workspace for my team

Tags: url, postman

In my Postman shared workspace, the URLs for my APIs and the data contained within them are not visible to my teammates.
I have checked the permissions I granted them, and they are also able to create new folders and API requests. However, the data within these APIs remains invisible to others.

Comment: Is the data in variables? If so, when this is only in the current value, this is not sync'd or shared with other team members. Can you provide a visual example of the problem you're facing?

Comment: @danny-dainton I am not getting any data in the URL fields, body (JSON) just we got the created folder and request names for the particular API's

Comment: I obviously have to ask, is everything saved?

Comment: @danny-dainton thankyou so much ! i haven't saved the url requests  ! now everything working ...